# Error while following Microsoft documentation on web part caching with PnPJS

Tags: spfx-webparts, pnpjs

Microsoft official documentation-
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-sp-pnp-js-with-spfx-web-parts

In the PnPjsExample.tsx part, this part of code has:

```
const spCache = spfi(this._sp).using(Caching("session"));
```

I'm getting this following error:

> "Type '"session"' has no properties in common with type 'ICachingProps'."

Don't know how to handle this error.
Checked on spfx documentation on PnpJS but can't find it.

Comment: What version of SharePoint Framework are you using? You can find out by running `npm list --depth=1 -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint`

Comment: Hi Rob Thanks for your response, I'm using 1.14.0 as of my current SharePoint Framework version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that familiar with PnPJS caching so I'm not 100% sure this is the best/recommended fix, but this code change will get the sample working:

```
import { Caching, ICachingProps } from "@pnp/queryable";

// ...

const cacheProps: ICachingProps = {
  store: "session"
};
const spCache = spfi(this._sp).using(Caching(cacheProps));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You Rob, it worked for me.